# restoring images to input type field from $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] on page refresh

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a PHP application, where I have 4 steps of a form submission like following,

`Form 1 on page 1. (on submit values are stored in sessions and user is redirected to form 2 page.)`

`Form 2 on page 2. (on submit values are stored in sessions and user is redirected to form 3 page.)`

`And so on.`

And total steps are 4. and on submissions of form number 4 I get values from sessions and store in database.

If user go back on any previous step like from step 3 to step 2 then I take values from sessions for step 2 and auto fill the form fields with their values.

Now I have to add an input type file in step two, but how can I reselect file for step 2 input type file if user go back from step three to step one.

Any help please?

Comment: Save the file permanently to a known location on your server, and store the location?

Comment: I am wanting to store files for complete inquiries only. Like if user fill all 4 forms then store files on server, otherwise not.

Comment: If you're never getting the fourth form, then destroy the file.

Comment: It's also notable, that you can't reselect a file programmatically in the form itself, a user must browse the file again. A user has to either to browse a new file, or maybe tick a box that informs your back-end, that they want to use the previously sent file instead.

Comment: For me the simplest solution will be to use Jquery Form wizard library, so unless user will not submit form the information will not be stored , or you can use jQuery Ajax in same library if you want to save that information in some temporary table or session.